# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ctypes (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for ctypes

Tags: pip, ctypes

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ctypes (from versions: )
```

No matching distribution found for ctypes

Comment: Ok..and the question is?

Comment: while impporting ctypes its giving me the error

Comment: what's the *Python* version that you are using/ and on what *OS*? And when you try importing it what is the error? And please, edit the question with that info, do not post it as comments.

Comment: python 3.5.0, windows 10, 64 bit, using pip install command in cmd prmt i want to install ctypes

Comment: Again: what's the error when importing ctypes? Add the code and the traceback **into the question**!.  Also what *Python* installation do you have? Is it from https://www.python.org? Try uninstalling, your current installation, download it (again) from the site and try reinstalling.

Comment: """""""Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ctypes (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for ctypes""""""""

Comment: yes i have installed it fromm python.org  and i have tried the method of installing again but no use

Answer (score 4):

[ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) is module from the standard library, you don't need to install it, it comes preinstalled with Python.

Comment: NoModuleName ctypes

Comment: That means you have a broken or at least incomplete Python installation. What platform, what hardware, what OS, what Python distribution?

Comment: windows 10, python 3.5.0 , pip install using cmd prmt,